# Can behat log in as an administrator for testing while using LDAP?

Tags: testing

I'm using the [Behat Drupal Extension](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalextension). When I try to run a behat test on a sandbox server, I see the following. I see that a temporary admin user is being create but it can't seem to log in. **How might I remedy this so that behat can login?**

```
$ behat

Feature: First   Playing with features and exploring

  @api   Scenario: Run cron                                           
# features/first.feature:6
    Given I am logged in as a user with the "administrator" role # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext::assertAuthenticatedByRole()
      Failed to log in as user 'ss5vWjZY' with role 'administrator' (Exception)
    When I run cron                                              # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext::assertCron()
    And am on "admin/reports/dblog"                              # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::visit()
    Then I should see the link "Cron run completed"              # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::assertLinkVisible()
```

I've changed my LDAP configuration back to mixed mode:

> [image]

And only admins are allowed to create a new account

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well. It turned out to be a problem with LDAP. Switching to Mixed Mode allow the DrupalExtension to function properly. Since we don't want mixed by default, I added a pre-test setup function

```
public static function prepare($scope)
     {
        $data = array(
          'sids' => array (
            'directory' => 'directory',
          ),
          'authenticationMode' => 1,
          'loginConflictResolve' => 2,
          'acctCreation' => 4,
          'loginUIUsernameTxt' => NULL,
          'loginUIPasswordTxt' => NULL,
          'ldapUserHelpLinkUrl' => NULL,
          'ldapUserHelpLinkText' => 'Logon Help',
          'emailOption' => 3,
          'emailUpdate' => 1,
          'allowOnlyIfTextInDn' => array (),
          'excludeIfTextInDn' => array (),
          'allowTestPhp' => '',
          'excludeIfNoAuthorizations' => NULL,
          'ssoRemoteUserStripDomainName' => NULL,
          'seamlessLogin' => NULL,
          'ldapImplementation' => NULL,
          'cookieExpire' => NULL,

        );
        variable_set('ldap_authentication_conf', $data);
     }
```

The key is the line `'authenticationMode' => 1,`

Comment: To clarify, this would be added as a method to the `FeatureContext` class?

Comment: OUTCOME: I added this function as a method to `FeatureContext` and it worked like a charm! Marking correct answer.

Comment: Why not do like `$mixed_authentication_mode = 1;` and then set `'authenticationMode' => $mixed_authentication_mode,` ... it seems by renaming the variables, and probably the function name `prepare()` you could make the code be more self explanitory, and rely less on magic numbers and conventions .... just saying.

Comment: That data array/naming is from the Drupal LDAP conf variable. I like keeping the definition the same so that it is easy to diff what I see in drush to my behat config.

Comment: I threw in a bounty after the fact to say thanks. You really helped me through a big hurdle.